# (409 Conflict) in response to MKACTIVITY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, svn

We have been having an issue for months now and I cannot find a possible solution.

We have a server X that hosts a webapp. This webapp, among other things, deals with a svn repository hosted in server Y. This server (repository) is reached using WeBDAV through `http://Y/svn/repository`

The issue is that sometimes and totally random I get following error when trying to create a new folder in the repository or commit a file (it fails basically in operations that require to commit something):

Svn::Error::RaDavRequestFailed: Server sent unexpected return value (409 Conflict) in response to MKACTIVITY request for '/svn/repository/certainPath';

There is another service S that makes requests to the webapp and causes the svn operations and I can tell that this service uses multiple threads (which I believe is somehow causing the problem but not sure about that).

I have searched all over the place but didn't really find anything useful. I know from another friend that they have that issue too and upgrading to svn 1.7 fixed the issue. In my case upgrading to a newer version is not that simple so I prefer to fix the issue and, of course, finally understand what the hell is going on!

Thanks!

Details:
Server X and Y have Snow Leopard
svn version in X is 1.6.17 (r1128011)
apache version in Y I don't know (no access)

Comment: 409s can be misleading.  I've seen them for incorrect file system permissions or on virtual servers where the disk is remote, a little blip in the network can cause this.  what OS is the svn server?  check the apache error logs and /var/log/messages

Comment: the svn server runs on snow leopard. It is really driving me crazy, I find no possible explanation for this and it happens totally random...